# Dataflow Datastore to GCS Template, javascriptTextTransformFunctionName Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I am using the Cloud Datastore to Cloud Storage Text template from Cloud Dataflow.

My python code correctly submits the request and uses `javascriptTextTransformFunctionName` to run the correct function in my Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Here is a minimized part of the code that is running

```
function format(inJson) {
var output = {};
output.administrator = inJson.properties.administrator.keyValue.path[0].id;

return output;
```

And here is the Json I am looking to format, cut down, but only the other children of "properties."

```
  "properties": {
    "administrator": {
      "keyValue": {
        "path": [
          {
            "kind": "Kind",
            "id": "5706504271298560"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read 
property "keyValue" from undefined in <eval> at line number 5
```

I understand what it is saying the error is, but I don't know why its happening. If you take the format function and that json and run it through your browser console you can easily test and see that it pulls out and returns an object with "administrator" equal to "5706504271298560".

Answer (score 0):

I did not found the solution to your problem but I expect to be of some help:

1. Found [this post](https://fantom.org/forum/topic/2506) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30156214/nashorn-typeerror-cannot-call-undefined-in-eval) with the same issue. The first one was fixed installing NodeJS library, the second one changing the kind of quotes for the `Java.Type()`.
2. [Nashorn official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/api.html): call `Java.type` with a fully qualified Java class *name*, and then to call the returned function to instantiate a class from JavaScript.